# How to properly redirect domain and display the updated domain in the address bar?

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I need to redirect traffic targeting a legacy domain (environment long gone) to our current system. I've setup a DNS IP redirect which sends the requests to our new environment successfully but the domain displayed in the address bar continues to reflect the legacy system.  i.e. instead of https://current_system/new it's displaying https://old_system/old, despite correctly reaching our updated system.  I simply want the site to reflect the current domain while supporting redirects from the retired infrastructure.  All site content has been moved to the new infrastructure but legacy URL's persist in the data.

I've tried to use mod_rewrite in httpd.conf but I don't know if that's best for this. The following does nothing.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old_system.company.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new_system.company.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Is it more appropriate to use proxypass?
Any suggestions please?  My apache and redirect knowledge is limited.
Thanks!

Comment: this question is better asked at https://serverfault.com